# Highlight multiple elements in bootstrap-tour

Tags: bootstrap-tour

I am using bootstrap tour highlight feature for a page. Apart from the element I have attached tour guide to, I want to highlight some other element as well without the tour guide being attached to the second element. Is there any possible work around for that?

Comment: Did you find a solution?